# Rotate left and back to the right for sign extension with (signed short) cast in C

Tags: c, casting, rotation, unsigned, signed

Previously, I had the following C code, through which I intended to do sign extension of variable 'sample' after a cast to 'signed short' of variable 'sample_unsigned'.

```
unsigned short sample_unsigned;
signed short sample;

sample = ((signed short) sample_unsigned << 4) >> 4;
```

In binary representation, I would expect 'sample' to have its most significant bit repeated 4 times. For instance, if:

```
sample_unsigned = 0x0800 (corresponding to "100000000000" in binary)
```

I understand 'sample' should result being:

```
sample = 0xF800 (corresponding to "1111100000000000" in binary)
```

However, 'sample' always ended being the same as 'sample_unsigned', and I had to split the assignment statement as below, which worked. Why this?

```
sample = ((signed short) sample_unsigned << 4);
sample >>= 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will not work. There is no gaurantee right shifting will preserve the sign. Even if, it would only work for 16 bit `int`. For >=32 bit `int` you have to replicate the sign manually into the upper bits, otherwise it just shifts the same data back and forth. In general, bitshifts of signed values are critical - see the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7 for details. Some constellations invoke undefined behaviour. It is better to avoid them and just work with unsigned integers.

For most platforms, the following works, however. It is not necessarily slower (on platforms with 16 bit `int`, it is likely even faster):

```
uint16_t usample;
int16_t ssample;

ssample = (int16_t)usample;
if ( ssample & 0x800 )
    ssample |= ~0xFFF;
```

The cast to `int16_t` is implementation defined; your compiler shall specify how it is performed. For (almost?) all recent implementations no extra operation is performed. Just verify in the generated code or your compiler documentation. The logical-or relies on `intX_t` using 2s complement which is guaranteed by the standard - as opposed to the standard types.

On 32 bit platforms, there might be an intrinsic instruction to sign-extend (e.g. ARM Cortex-M3/4 SBFX). Or the compiler provides a builtin function. Depending on your use-case and speed requirements, it might be suitable to use them.

**Update:**

An alternative approach would be using a bitfield structure:

```
struct {
    int16_t val : 12;    // assuming 12 bit signed value like above
} extender;

extender.val = usample;
ssample = extender.val;
```

This might result in using the same assembler instructions I proposed above.

Comment: I was aware that sign extension by right shifts produces undefined behavior. I'm working on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04, and after checking my gcc's  documentation, I decided to give it a try. The reason I need to do such operation is because I'm capturing data from a hardware platform that delivers 10-bit signed values, which, later on, I need to save as ASCII. I guess using `uint16_t` and `int16_t`, as you suggested, should be a more stable solution.

Comment: @CarlosCastro: I already anticipated this kind of application. I use it myself on embedded systems. Just don't rely on that! The simple conditional above will liely not take more clocks on a platform with conditional move instructions (IIRC, x64 does provide such, ARM definitively does). Note that this is - like the code in your question - is for 12 bit signed integers, not 10 bit; so you have to adjust the masks! If it is just for conversion, however, there might be simpler techniques. If you can spare the memory space, you could even generate a simple lookup-table.

Comment: @CarlosCastro: I updated the answer a bit. Feel free to upvote, if the answer helped. If you need best performance, just benchmark the variants (but be careful **what** you actually benchmark)

Answer (score 0):

It is because `(signed short) sample_unsigned` is automatically converted to `int` as operand due to interger promotion.

```
sample = (signed short)((signed short) sample_unsigned << 4) >> 4;
```

will work as well.

Comment: Changing the sign by bitshift is undefined behaviour. And `signed short` will still be coerced to `int`.

Comment: And right shifting a `signed` is not guaranteed to preserve the sign anyway (it can even be UB).

Comment: The internal (signed short) is probably not needed, just need to cast to signed just before doing the right shift. As mentioned, this is environment specific, but will work for most two's complement systems.

Comment: It will not work anyway this way. I ran into the same trap as you and OP about the shifts.

Comment: @rcgldr Yes, this should work just as well: `sample = (signed short)(sample_unsigned << 4) >> 4;` although the result is implementation defined, it should work for most 2's complement systems.

Comment: Technically `sample = (signed short)(sample_unsigned << 4) >> 4` could raise an implementation-defined signal due to overflow, but most implementations ignore integer overflows.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it would be coerced to `int`. Thanks for the replies! Then, what could be a more (or the most) effective way to implement sign extension? I need this because I'm capturing data from some hardware unaware of software types.

Comment: @IanAbbott: On systems with 32 bit `int` The sign from the input will not even reach the sign-bit. So even **iff** right-shift preserves the sign (which is not guaranteed), it will only shift back and forth the same data. However, the shift does not "work for most 2s complement systems". On some widely used 8 and 16 bit MCUs, there is no arithmetical right shift instruction and the compiler will likely use logical shifts which do not replicate the sign.